# How prove this $\sigma_{2}=\sigma_{1}\sigma\Longleftrightarrow \ker(\sigma_{1})\subset\sigma_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

let $\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2}$ be a linear transformation from an n-dimension vector space $V$,show that follow two  condition are equivalent

$$(1):\ker(\sigma_{1})\subset\ker(\sigma_{2})$$

(2)there exist transformation $\sigma$ from $V$,such $$\sigma_{2}=\sigma \sigma_{1}$$

My try: since
$$\ker(\sigma_{1})\subset\ker(\sigma_{2})\Longrightarrow \dim(ker(\sigma_{1}))<\dim(\ker(\sigma_{2}))$$
then I can't,Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\ker T\subset \ker S\Rightarrow S=rT$ when $S$ and $T$ are linear functionals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60460/ker-t-subset-ker-s-rightarrow-s-rt-when-s-and-t-are-linear-functionals)

Answer (score 0):

- Suppose that $\sigma_2 = \sigma \sigma_1$. Then for all $x \in \ker \sigma_1$, one has $\sigma_2(x) = \sigma(\sigma_1(x))=\sigma(0)=0$. This proves that $\ker \sigma_1 \subset \ker \sigma_2$.
- Suppose that $\ker \sigma_1 \subset \ker \sigma_2$ and let $S$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $S \oplus \ker \sigma_1= V$. The map $f \colon S \to \sigma_1(V)$ defined by $f(x) = \sigma_1(x)$ for all $x \in S$ is an isomorphism (check this). Let $\sigma \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ be an arbitrary endomorphism (check the existence) such that
  $$\forall x \in S,\quad\sigma(x) = \sigma_2(f^{-1}(x)),$$
  so that $\sigma\sigma_1(x)=\sigma_2(x)$ for all $x \in S$. Finally, notice that the assumption $\ker \sigma_1 \subset \ker \sigma_2$ implies that $\sigma\sigma_1(x)=\sigma_2(x)$ for all $x \in \ker \sigma_1$. By linearity, we conclude that $\sigma_2 = \sigma\sigma_1$ because $S \oplus \ker \sigma_1= V$.
- Actually, under condition (1), the non-empty set $\{\sigma \in \mathcal{L}(V) : \sigma_2 = \sigma\sigma_1\}$ is an affine subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ of dimension $(\dim \ker \sigma_1)^2$.