# Linear transformations with the same kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

If two linear transformations between finite-dimensional vector spaces, we say

$$L,T : V \longrightarrow W$$

has the same kernel, and kernel is not the space zero. Is $T$ a multiple of $L$?

Comment: Of course not. For example are bijections $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ multiples?

Comment: What would happen if $W = \mathbb{C}$ and $Ker(T)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

No, for example take the linear map $f\in\operatorname{End} K^2$ associated (using the standard basis) to the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1&0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
This matrix is invertible and hence $f$ has trivial kernel. The identity map on $K^2$ is also invertible (of course!), but $f$ and $\operatorname{id}$ are not multiples of each other.

For a general counterexample to your edited question. Let $K$ be a field and $n>1$.
Consider the maps
$f, g\in \operatorname{End} K^n$ defined by
$f(x)=(x_1,0,\ldots,0)$ and $g(x)=(x_1,\ldots,x_1)$.

Comment: What would happen if I add the condition Ker(T)≠0?

Comment: It would still fail. For example, row operations (multiplication by elementary matrices) preserves the kernel, but will almost always yield matrices that are not multiples of each other. Thus you can start with your favorite matrix that is not of full rank, perform some row operations and get a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think I should have asked what happens in the case of linear functions.

Comment: These are all linear functions!

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I meant LINEAR FUNCTIONALS,

Comment: Yes, it is true then, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890101/if-two-functionals-have-the-same-kernel-then-one-is-a-multiple-of-the-other and the two linked questions at the top.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Take square matrices of order $2$ like $A=[a_{ij}]$ where $a_{11}=1, a_{12}=a_{21}=a_{22}=0$ and $B=[b_{ij}]$ where $b_{21}=1, b_{11}=b_{12}=b_{22}=0$