# Is the alternative proof correct? if not why?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

([If $\ker f\subset \ker g$ where $f,g $ are non-zero linear functionals then show that $f=cg$ for some $c\in F$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050228/if-ker-f-subset-ker-g-where-f-g-are-non-zero-linear-functionals-then-show))
I came across such a task in the textbook only with the condition
if $kerf= kerg$

$V = kerf + V/kerf$

Let's say there are two independent vectors in V/kerf
$e_1$ $e_2$

$f(e_1) \neq 0$
$f(e_2) \neq 0$

since $f$ functional there is a non-zero linear combination
$x_1*f(e_1) + x_2*f(e_2)$ = $0 $ mean $f(x_1*e_1 + x_2*e_2) = 0$

$x_1 = 1  $

$x_2 = -f(e_1)/f(e_2)$

$x_1*e_1 +x_2*e_2 \neq 0$

$x = x_1*e_1 + x_2*e_2
$

x belongs kerf and V/kerf , contradiction

$dimV/kerf  \leq 1$

and $f(x) = a*g(x)  <=> f(e) = a*g(e)$ for any  basis vector $e$ (Hamel basis)
but we have maximum one   basis vector  for which f(x) is not zero

for a finite-dimensional space it can be shown that the dimension $dimkerf = n-1$
=>$dimV/kerf$ = $n-dimkerf$ = 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There is a more general fact: if $\ker f_1\cap\ldots \cap \ker f_n\subset\ker g$ then $g$ belongs to the linear span of $f_1,\ldots,f_n.$ For $n=1$ we get $g=cf_1.$ Since  $g\neq 0$ then $c\neq 0.$